# Storing multiple Facebook accounts for a user

Tags: authentication, meteor

Basically I need to authenticate my users with their Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn accounts. A user can have more than one Facebook account, more than one Twitter account etc. Should I use meteor's own authentication modules or should I write my own OAuth process to store all user tokens?